# WebApp on Visual Studio Mac Not Running

Tags: visual-studio-mac

I am running a web project for a client on VS Mac.  It is a .NET Core 3.1 web api project.  When I try to run debug on the run configuration, it builds fine and starts up fine, but it doesn't auto open the browser and I cannot access the controller methods via localhost.  It's like it's not listening to my localhost or port.  The Run Configuration is set with an App URL pointing to "localhost:9017" and the "Open URL in web browser when app starts" is checked. The URL is "api/health".  I don't even see the log for "Now listening on localhost:9017" in the Application Output.  What else am I not considering?  It doesn't work dotnet run, or through vs code.

Here is the launch json

```
    {
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/my.project/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/my.project.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/src/my.project",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "action": "openExternally",
                "pattern": "\\bNow listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)",
                "uriFormat": "%s/api/health"
            },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "dev"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out not to be a problem with dotnet run or visual studios.  I ran the code in a docker container and got the same result.  It turns out the team had add the below line in Program.cs file and it was defaulting the listening URL to http://[:]:9017.  For windows machines it was working with localhost fine.

```
.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                webBuilder.UseUrls("http://+:9017");
            });
```